# OpenAPI - Get arbitrary query parameters

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have an endpoint like this :

```
api/employees?limit=2&name=Palani&age=20
```

Here, the `limit` is keyword that is publicised to the users. But `name` and `age` are arbitrary parameters. For another resource, like `Organization`, an arbitrary parameter could be `foundIn`.

In openapi spec, I have

```
   api/employees :
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: limit
          required: false
          schema:
            type: integer
```

I am using codegen plugin `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` where in the server controller, I want to capture all the arbitrary parameter. How can I extend my openapi spec to get the params apart from `limit`. If there is a way to get all the query params in a single array, that would be a help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can extend the parameters like this.

```
api/employees :
get:
  parameters:
    - name: limit
      in: query
      required: false
      schema:
        type: integer
    - name: name
      in: query
      nullable: true
      schema:
        type: string
    - name: age
      in: query
      nullable: true
      schema:
        type: integer
```